# multiple connection strings vb.net

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

I have three connection strings in my config file.
I want to detect the name of the connection string which is connected at the moment.

(All three databases are remote and have different purposes).

I want to detect the name at different places in my project.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for OleDBConnection : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use the property ConnectionString of that object to know which connection is used.

But if you have three different databases for different purpose, I would suggest to use three Connection objects...